# Private inheritance got "an inaccessible base" error

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

Here is MY_STRING class implementation. Since I wish only some of specified interfaces visible I use private inheritance instead of public.

```
class MY_STRING : private std::string
{
public:
   MY_STRING() : std::string() {}
   MY_STRING(const char* s) : std::string(s) {}
   using std::string::operator +=;
};
int main()
{
    MY_STRING s = "1", x = "2";
    s += x;
}
```

But I got a compilation error: 'std::basic_string' is an inaccessible base of 'MY_STRING'.
Even though I had a ugly solution as follows

```
const MY_STRING& operator += (const MY_STRING& s) { static_cast<std::string*>
    (this)->operator+=(*static_cast<const std::string*>(&s)); return *this; }
```

I still wonder why the error arises and if there is more elegant solution.

Comment: just curious - why are you subclassing?

Comment: I wish MY_STRING have some similar interfaces such =, += as std::string, plus one extra const char * operator function, excluding those iteration interfaces. It is easiest to inherit directly from std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `std::string::operator+=` from within member functions of `MY_STRING`. Outsiders cannot use it.   You can't "promote" it with `using` or anything.

That's what private inheritance means. Private inheritance is, in effect, the same as having a private member variable, just that syntax is different within the member functions of `MY_STRING`.

To fix this you will either have to not use private inheritance, or write a forwarding function for those that you want to publish.

Also, your forwarding function seems unnecessarily complicated, try:

```
MY_STRING &operator+= (MY_STRING const &s)
    { std::string::operator+=(s); return *this; }
```

You don't want to return a const reference when called on a non-const object (and += doesn't make sense for a const object).